# swift mapkit didChangeDragState not called

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkannotationview

`didChangeDragState` not called when I have `didSelectAnnotationView`, so on every time the `didSelectAnnotationView` is called but `didChangeDragState` dont.

So when I remove the `didSelectAnnotationView`, `didChangeDragState` called normally,

Please help me,

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: what I mean is that didChangeDragState not called when I create the didSelectAnnotationView function

Comment: I am facing the same issue... please help